# performance issue when inserting large records

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql

I am parsing string into comma separated and inserting them to global table. The performance is good when inserting around 5k records, performance sucks if the inserting record is around 40k+. The global table has only one column. I thought using bulk fetch and forall will increase the performance, but it’s not the case so far. How can I rewrite below insertion query or any other ways this can be achieved for inserting large records? help will be highly appreciated. I did testing by running insert query by its own and it’s taking long time to process if data size is large.

```
//large string
emp_refno in CLOB;

CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE employee( emp_refno IN CLOB ) AS 
    c_limit PLS_INTEGER := 1000;

      CURSOR token_cur IS
        WITH inputs(str) AS
             ( SELECT to_clob(emp_refno)
                    FROM   dual ),
        prep(s,n,token,st_pos,end_pos ) AS
           (
             SELECT ','|| str || ',',-1,NULL,NULL,1
             FROM   inputs
             UNION ALL
             SELECT s, n + 1,substr(s, st_pos, end_pos - st_pos),
                    end_pos + 1,instr(s, ',', 1, n + 3)
             FROM   prep
             WHERE  end_pos != 0
      )
    SELECT token
    FROM   prep
    WHERE  n > 0;

    TYPE token_t
    IS
      TABLE OF CLOB;
      rec_token_t TOKEN_T;
BEGIN
   OPEN token_cur;
   LOOP
     FETCH token_cur bulk collect
     INTO  rec_token_t limit c_limit;

     IF rec_token_t.count > 0 THEN
          forall rec IN rec_token_t.first ..rec_token_t.last
          INSERT INTO globaltemp_emp 
          VALUES  (  rec_token_t(rec) );
          COMMIT;
      END IF;
      EXIT
      WHEN rec_token_t.count = 0;
   END LOOP;
   OPEN p_resultset FOR
      SELECT e.empname,
             e.empaddress,
             f.department
      FROM   employee e
      join   department f
      ON     e.emp_id = t.emp_id
      AND    e.emp_refno IN
             (
                    SELECT emp_refno
                    FROM   globaltemp_emp) //USING gtt IN subquery
END;
```

Comment: Try to move commit after end of the loop not inside the loop.

Comment: @Kumar I tried moving commit  after the loop still the performance did not improve. Stuck with this performance issue

Comment: Where does this string of EMP REFNOs come from? Something has concatenated them, it might be better to approach it from there.

Comment: @APC emp_refno is coming from java. I am parsing them to a comma seperated string into controller and sending them to proc. Like Map<String, Object> listemp = new Hashmap(): listemp.put(“emp_refno”, delemitedemp_refno”); any suggestion What can be done here

Comment: Before anything else, you should find out if the `select` is slow or the `insert`. Change the procedure to do the same, except the `insert`, and check the required run time.

Comment: So how do they get into the Java? Is a user typing 50000 Ref Nos into a GUI? I presume not. So where do they come from?

Comment: Is it typo `ON  e.emp_id = t.emp_id` should be `ON e.emp_id = f.emp_id`

Comment: @APC user uploads text file and I parse that text file as a comma seperated string and pass it to Oracle DB. I did some testing: insert query gets very slow when data is large. I am using bulk collect and forall should have been faster but it’s slow for large data

Comment: @APC emp_refno is string but I am passing it to DB as CLOB as varchar only allows upto 4000 bytes

Comment: *"user uploads text file "* Disco! That's the information we needed to know. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have adapted a function which gives better performance.For 90k records, it returns in 13 seconds.Also reduce the c_limit to 250

You can adapt the below

```
  CREATE OR replace FUNCTION pipe_clob ( p_clob       IN CLOB,
                                          p_max_lengthb IN INTEGER DEFAULT 4000,
                                          p_rec_delim   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '
    ' )
      RETURN sys.odcivarchar2list pipelined authid current_user AS
      /*
    Break CLOB into VARCHAR2 sized bites.
    Reduce p_max_lengthb if you need to expand the VARCHAR2
    in later processing.
    Last record delimiter in each bite is not returned,
    but if it is a newline and the output is spooled
    the newline will come back in the spooled output.
    Note: this cannot work if the CLOB contains more than
    <p_max_lengthb> consecutive bytes without a record delimiter.
    */
      l_amount           INTEGER;
      l_offset           INTEGER;
      l_buffer           VARCHAR2(32767 byte);
      l_out              VARCHAR2(32767 byte);
      l_buff_lengthb     INTEGER;
      l_occurence        INTEGER;
      l_rec_delim_length INTEGER := length(p_rec_delim);
      l_max_length       INTEGER;
      l_prev_length      INTEGER;
      BEGIN
        IF p_max_lengthb > 4000 THEN
          raise_application_error(-20001, 'Maximum record length (p_max_lengthb) cannot be greater than 4000.');
        ELSIF p_max_lengthb < 10 THEN
          raise_application_error(-20002, 'Maximum record length (p_max_lengthb) cannot be less than 10.');
        END IF;
        IF p_rec_delim IS NULL THEN
          raise_application_error(-20003, 'Record delimiter (p_rec_delim) cannot be null.');
        END IF;
        /* This version is limited to 4000 byte output, so I can afford to ask for 4001
    in case the record is exactly 4000 bytes long.
    */
        l_max_length:=dbms_lob.instr(p_clob,p_rec_delim,1,1)-1;
        l_prev_length:=0;
        l_amount := l_max_length + l_rec_delim_length;
        l_offset := 1;
        WHILE (l_amount = l_max_length + l_rec_delim_length
        AND
        l_amount > 0)
        LOOP
          BEGIN
            dbms_lob.READ ( p_clob, l_amount, l_offset, l_buffer );
          EXCEPTION
          WHEN no_data_found THEN
            l_amount := 0;
          END;
          IF l_amount = 0 THEN
            EXIT;
          ELSIF lengthb(l_buffer) <= l_max_length THEN
            pipe ROW(rtrim(l_buffer, p_rec_delim));
            EXIT;
          END IF;
          l_buff_lengthb := l_max_length + l_rec_delim_length;
          l_occurence := 0;
          WHILE l_buff_lengthb > l_max_length
          LOOP
            l_occurence := l_occurence                                      + 1;
            l_buff_lengthb := instrb(l_buffer,p_rec_delim, -1, l_occurence) - 1;
          END LOOP;
          IF l_buff_lengthb < 0 THEN
            IF l_amount = l_max_length + l_rec_delim_length THEN
              raise_application_error( -20004, 'Input clob at offset '
              ||l_offset
              ||' for lengthb '
              ||l_max_length
              ||' has no record delimiter' );
            END IF;
          END IF;
          l_out := substrb(l_buffer, 1, l_buff_lengthb);
          pipe ROW(l_out);
          l_prev_length:=dbms_lob.instr(p_clob,p_rec_delim,l_offset,1)-1;--san temp
          l_offset := l_offset + nvl(length(l_out),0) + l_rec_delim_length;
          l_max_length:=dbms_lob.instr(p_clob,p_rec_delim,l_offset,1)-1;--san temp
          l_max_length:=l_max_length-l_prev_length;
          l_amount := l_max_length  + l_rec_delim_length;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN;
      END;
```

and then use like the below in the cursor in your procedure

```
           CURSOR token_cur IS

            select  * from table (pipe_clob(emp_refno||',',10,','));
```

Comment: this is the same query you suggested me last time- this query is perfect. I implemented what you suggested above works perfectly for small data but performance is very slow for large data. Do you think delemeting comma separated string in WITH CTE clause might be causing issue. Thank you for your effort

Comment: i have done changes in limit and some if condition try it out and let me know

Comment: yes I tried above updated query, still it’s slow with 50000 emp_ref records

Comment: we can split it into two one for insert and another for select query to check where the issue is ,for now i will remove the select query to check the bottle neck

Comment: I did some testing separately, inserting query is taking time when data is large.

Comment: given one more suggestion,please try it and let me know

Comment: I tried that and also I tried only inserting data(without select) but got same issue with larger data. Is it possible to IM you anywhere ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213632/discussion-between-psaraj12-and-user10806781).

Comment: @psataj12 this is working perfect. Thank you very much for such a great effort. You are a great mentor ....

Answer (score 0):

Three quick suggestions:

1. Perform commit for around 1000(or in batches) records rather than doing for each.
2. Replace in with exists for the Ref cursor.
3. Index globaltemp_emp.emp_refno if it doesn't have already.

Additionally recommend to run explain plan for each of the DML operation to check for any odd behaviour.

Comment: ’sCorner global table is indexed. how can I perform commit for around 1000 record or in batches? Do you have any example ?

Comment: @user10806781 Is it default GTT(delete rows on commit) or GTT preserve rows on commit?.

Comment: @Kumar it’s perverse rows on commit

Comment: It’s bit old school,Add a counter and increment the same and commit when it reaches 1000 and then reset the counter.

Answer (score 0):

> user uploads text file and I parse that text file as a comma seperated string and pass it to Oracle DB.

You are doing a bunch of work to turn that file into a string and then another bunch of work to convert that string into a table. As many people have observed before me, the best performance comes from not doing work we don't have to do.

In this case this means you should load the file's contents directly into the database. We can do this with an external table. This is a mechanism which allows us to query data from a file on the server using SQL. It would look something like this:

```
create table emp_refno_load
   (emp_refno            varchar2(24))
    organization external
      (type oracle_loader
       default directory file_upload_dir
       access parameters
         (records delimited by newline
          fields (employee_number      char(24)
         )
       )
    location ('some_file.txt')
   );
```

Then you can discard your stored procedure and temporary table and re-write your query to something like this:

```
SELECT e.empname,
       e.empaddress,
       f.department
FROM   emp_refno_load  l
       join employee   e ON l.emp_refno = e.emp_refno
       join department f ON e.emp_id    = f.emp_id
```

The one snag with external tables is they require access to an OS directory (`file_upload_dir` in my example above) and some database security policies are weird about that. However the performance benefits and simplicity of approach should carry the day. 
[Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-44323E01-7D72-45EC-915A-99E596769D9E.htm#SUTIL011).

An external table is undoubtedly the most performative approach (until you hit millions of roads and then you need [SQL*Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-8D037494-07FA-4226-B507-E1B2ED10C144.htm#SUTIL3311) ).

Comment: I cannot create loader or external tables. The best I can use us Global temp tables